# dynamic background image not display on bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I want to dynamic change the background image and details on bootstrap modal by using ajax I get all images from database and my modal is working fine every id showing right data I'm facing problem showing background image

here's modal code image
[image]

Ajax code
[image]

I do getting right URL for image like https://example.net/uploads/16188133891985.jpg and right image for every id problem is when I pass that image to modal body it's not working and modal look like this

[image]

if anyone can help me what I'm missing my ajax working fine I'm getting all data as well as image

thank you

Comment: Hi Yasir, it would be really helpful if you could please put down your example somewhere online instead of code snippets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you setting the attribute 'data-bg-src'? That wont change a background image.
You have to change the style, which with jquery would be something like:

```
$('#aboutModal').css('background-image', 'url('+pathToImage+')');
```